# Why do I have an "any any" rule in iptables at the top and one at the bottom?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, rhel7

Hoping someone can clear this up for me. I'm on RHEL7.1 and I noticed that in iptables I have a rule that allows anything incoming. I ran this command to get the line numbers and interfaces just to make sure:

```
iptables --line-numbers -L -v --verbose
```

and this is the output. (first line only)

```
1      30M 2931M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

This is from the input chain. Now here is the last line of the input chain:

```
42    243K   22M DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Now, I also have many rules in the input chain in between. But I do not understand why I would even need these with the "any any" rule at the very top. Doesn't this defeat the purpose of having iptables running? Do I have a mis-configured firewall here?

Comment: Read the first rule in its entirety.

Comment: @MIchael is that rule actually needed? What would happen if I were to remove it and restart iptables? I am guessing if its related to an exsiting connection whatever that connection was would be dropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first rule just accept RELATED and ESTABLISHED connections, not NEW ones. You have this rule probably because you're blocking everything and just allowing some services, like HTTP, DNS, etc. At the end, everything that doesn't match any previous rule will be dropped.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So I see that I have packets associated with this rule. How do I track down what connection or process they belong to?

Comment: @user53029 They belong to every connection ever made by the machine, in both directions.